# Disable Eureka Server to remove registry which is not sending heartbeat

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am using Netflix Eureka Server for my spring boot microservices. However, i saw that if a microservice is unable to send heartbeat it does not marks the service as DOWN instead it shows an warning message in the dashboard. But my expected behavior is, if a service can not send heartbeat it should be marked as DOWN also it should not be evicted immediately. It should show the service as DOWN for at least 1 day.

Did anyone expected this behavior and implemented as is? I believe it should be configured with following properties

```
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalSeconds=
eureka.server.evictionIntervalTimerInSeconds=
```

But as a beginner i thought i should take suggestions from the community.